# EF core - Creating a migration for a database without a connection string and in another class library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to create a migration for a second and subsequent databases that's in a class library different from the project that uses it. There is a wrinkle. I will never know the connection string until a user logs in and I can get it from a catalog database (saas).

For the catalog database I used the solution from [this](https://codingblast.com/entityframework-core-idesigntimedbcontextfactory/) site. That was fine - This database has its connection string in appsettings.json and can uses dependency injection.

The client databases are all going to be identical using the same migration. My problem is, I dont know how to create this initial migration from the Package Manager Console..

I did try to run this:

```
dotnet ef migrations add INITIAL --context APIcontext -s ../Jobsledger.API
```

and its given me the following error:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext.

Which I expected.

Given that CodingBlast solution (above) to running migrations in a different class library requires a connection which I don't have and requires the database connection to be registered at startup...

..and given that this migration is to be used by every user database to be created how do I create it and of course use it?

Answer (score 0):

I did answer similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67881156/2800222).

You can implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` where you instantiate DbContext with no connection string.

For the different library, you can use --project and --startup-project parameters.

Here is an example what I'm using to generate migrations script:

`dotnet ef migrations script --context MyDbContext --output migrations.sql --project "./MyApp.Data" --startup-project "./MyApp.Data"`