# EF Core - Create a migration without connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have been ranging across multiple questions, tutorials and examples for something that fits this problem.

What if I don't know my connection string at the time I want to create my first initial migration? Given I am given the opportunity to set the connection string at the time of instantiating context eg:

```
var connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=JobsLedgerDB;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0";
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connection);

using (var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

As described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)..

If you need to have a connection string to run migrations then for those situations where you don't have one (Tenant database where you get a connection string from a user account) how do you run an initial migration??

Do you create a dummy connection string to create the migration.. seems dodgy to me. I would love some input on this.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your question correctly. But you do need to test out your app and so at some point of time you would need to have a working database, right? For development I'd normally use my local DB (SQL Server 2017), and the connection string would be pointing to the local server.

Comment: Im developing the solution. The structure is - tenant details reside in a catalog database. Each Tenant has a database connection as part of the setup. The problem is I want to create an initial migration but it appears you need the connection string set up in options.. cart before the horse.. I dont have a connection string as I get that in the process of a user (connected to a tenant) logs on.. so how do I create that initial migration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [EF core - Creating a migration for a database without a connection string and in another class library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55980487/ef-core-creating-a-migration-for-a-database-without-a-connection-string-and-in)

Comment: I suugest you edit the previous question instead of asking basically the same again.

Comment: Did you find something about this? I was also adding migrations with a dummy connection string, but when it comes to `Remove-Migration`, I guess it does not accept a dummy string, it fails.

Comment: how did you fixed it, I've got  the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory` that will be used instead your host builder in the design time. UseSqlServer now has a parameterless overload.

It will look like this and has to be in the same assembly as the db context or in the startup project:

```
public class MyAppDbContextFactory: IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyAppDbContext>
{
    public MyAppDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyAppDbContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer();
            
        return new MyAppDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}
```

More details can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory

Comment: In my case, EF generates only one statement in a SQL script - creating "__EFMigrationsHistory" table.